# JQuery erratic behavior of cloned links

Tags: jquery, clone, hyperlink

I have links to pages of data displayed at the top of my page. I've cloned this to the bottom of the page as well. The problem lies in attempting to remove the `href` attribute of the active page. This works for the top row of links, but not for the bottom.

```
<div class="pages"></div>

<div id="workspace"><br/></div>

<div id="pagesclone"></div>
```

jquery:

```
//Generate page number links
for (x = 1; x < 6; x++) {
    $('.pages').append(' <a href="#" class="links">' + x + '</a> ');    
}

page = 1;

//Function for link clicks
$('.links').click(function() {
    //"You clicked .."
   current = $(this).html();
   $('#workspace').html('You clicked ' + current);

    //shifting the active page    
   $('.links').slice(page - 1, page).attr('href', '#'); //activate preceeding link
   page = $(this).html(); //reset page number to the link clicked
   $('.links').slice(page - 1, page).removeAttr('href'); //remove href attribute
});


//Clone the top row of links to the bottom
$('.pages').clone(true, true).appendTo('#pagesclone');
```

Everything looks correct to me. How could I make the cloned links on the lower page also have the `href` attribute remove when clicked, and vice-versa?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JshnC/10/

Comment: Why global variables everywhere? That might be a source of problems. `x`, `page`, `current` are global...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your `page` index only points to the elements of the first row. If you add half the length of $(".links") you get the index of the element of the second row, and you can make it work.

There is a working (but ugly) version taking this approach at http://jsfiddle.net/dLKfA/

You can make your code much nicer if you introduce [some more classes](http://jsfiddle.net/BG8WF/):

When generating:

```
$('.pages').append(' <a href="#" class="links link-' + x + '">' + x + '</a> ');
```

Then when updating:

```
$('.links.link-' + page).attr('href', '#'); //activate preceeding link
page = $(this).html(); //set page number to the link clicked
$('.links.link-' + page).removeAttr('href'); //remove href attribute
```

But also, what @elclanrs said about globals. They are very likely to bite you at some point.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the most efficient however [here is one way](http://jsfiddle.net/JshnC/12/):

```
var link = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$.each(link, function(a) {
    $(".pages").append("<a href='#' class='a" + a + "'>" + link[a] + "</a>");
});

$("a").click(function() {
    $("." + $(this).attr('class')).removeAttr("href");
});​
```